# Thinking sphinx without condition on array of id is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I am using `ruby 1.9.3p392` `rails 3.2.21` `thinking sphinx 3.1.0` and `Sphinx 2.2.4-id64-release`

`user_index.rb` file is :-

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :user, :with => :active_record do
  indexes first_name, :sortable => true
  indexes last_name
  indexes email
  indexes user_name
  indexes company_id
  indexes id
  indexes user_type_id
  indexes department.name
  indexes department.id, :as => :department_id
end
```

When i search as:-

```
assigned_user_ids = [372, 373, 374, 375, 367, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380]
@users = User.search(Riddle::Query.escape(params[:search]), 
    :conditions => {:company_id => @company.id}, 
    :without => {:id => assigned_user_ids}, :per_page => PAGINATION_SIZE, 
    :page => params[:page])
```

But it is still showing the `user` with `id = 372`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here:

The first is that you're using fields instead of attributes for any non-string data, and that means some filters aren't going to work reliably. The second issue is that `id` is used by Sphinx internally, so you should either use Thinking Sphinx's automatic attribute `sphinx_internal_id`, or add an alias to your own attribute.

So, I would recommend the following index definition instead:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :user, :with => :active_record do
  indexes first_name, :sortable => true
  indexes last_name
  indexes email
  indexes user_name
  indexes department.name

  has company_id
  has user_type_id
  has department.id, :as => :department_id
end
```

And then your search would be:

```
assigned_user_ids = [372, 373, 374, 375, 367, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380]
@users = User.search(Riddle::Query.escape(params[:search]), 
  :with     => {:company_id => @company.id}, 
  :without  => {:sphinx_internal_id => assigned_user_ids},
  :per_page => PAGINATION_SIZE, 
  :page     => params[:page]
)
```

In a completely unrelated note: unless this search is only being used by administrators, I would recommend you *not* have email addresses in your indexed data. Allowing people to search by email address is a security risk in most situations.